# window skin according OS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, skinning

I try to have a specific window skin according operating system.

See below my skin.

```
    <s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
         xmlns:Layout="skin.Layout.*"
         alpha.disabledGroup="0.5"
         creationComplete="sparkskin1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("fr.inter.ui.windowSkin.wCustomWindow")]
</fx:Metadata>


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected function btResize_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );
            stage.nativeWindow.startResize();
        }

        protected function btResize_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, btResize_mouseOutHandler );             
        }


        protected function btResize_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, btResize_mouseUpHandler );



        }

        protected function sparkskin1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

            if (NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon)
            {
                this.currentState = "supportsDockIcon";//mac
            }
            else
            {
                this.currentState = "supportsSystemTray";
            }
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="disabledAndInactive" stateGroups="disabledGroup, inactiveGroup" />
    <s:State name="maximizedGroup"/>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledGroup" />
    <s:State name="normalAndInactive" stateGroups="inactiveGroup" />
    <s:State name="supportsDockIcon" />
    <s:State name="supportsSystemTray"/>
</s:states>

<s:Rect id="backgroundRect"
        left="0"
        right="0"
        top="0"
        bottom="0"
        alpha="0"
        >
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Group bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
         top="0"  
         >
    <!--Fond de la fenetre-->
    <s:Rect bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            top="0"
            radiusX="8" radiusY="8" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#656565" alpha=".7" />
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Group height="38" id="moveArea"
             left="0" right="0" >

        <!--Barre bleu avec filet-->
        <s:Rect  height="25" left="10" right="10" top="10">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#055a90" />
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>


        <s:BitmapImage id="icon"
                       left.supportsSystemTray="5" right.supportsDockIcon="5"
                       verticalCenter="0" />

        <s:Label id="titleDisplay"
                 styleName="swindowTitle"
                 left.supportsSystemTray="60" left.supportsDockIcon="{this.width/2}"
                 top="18" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalCenter="0"
                 />

        <!--Zone de bouton-->

        <s:HGroup right.supportsSystemTray="12" left.supportsDockIcon="12" verticalCenter="0">

            <s:Button id="btMinimize" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.MinimizeButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.MinimizeButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

            <s:Button id="btMaximize" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.MaximizeButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.MaximizeButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

            <s:Button id="closeButton" buttonMode="true" 
                      skinClass.supportsSystemTray="skin.components.CloseButtonSkin"
                      skinClass.supportsDockIcon="skin.components.CloseButtonSkinM"
                      verticalCenter="0"/>

        </s:HGroup>

    </s:Group>

    <!--Fond de la zone principale-->

    <s:Rect id="background" left="10" top="35" right="10" bottom="10">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="-90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#edf0f7"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#fcfbfb" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!--Zone dans laquelle les elements vont se positionner-->


    <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="15" right="15" top="43" bottom="15" minWidth="0"
             minHeight="0" width="100%" height="100%">

    </s:Group>



</s:Group>
<s:Button height="15" id="btResize" width="15"
          bottom="0" right="0"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" 
          mouseDown="btResize_mouseDownHandler(event)"
          buttonMode="true"/>
```

When windows is loading firt, buttons appear well.
But if window is desactivate and after activate, MacOs and Windows buttons appear.

I don't know how to solve that, could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to set the Skin's `currentState` directly from within the Skin because the `hostComponent` should take care of that. When you deactivate and re-activate the Window, the hostComponent will set the Skin state back to one of its original states (e.g. `normal`) and hence disregards your two custom states.

If you want to set the Skin's state based on certain conditions you should override the [getCurrentSkinState()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html#getCurrentSkinState%28%29) method of the hostComponent. But in this particular case I don't think that would be the right approach, because it would be too complicated.

The easiest solution here I think would be to override the Skin's `updateDisplayList()` method to position your elements. This is the method that takes care of correctly displaying all the elements in your Skin.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            if (NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon) {
                titleDisplay.left = width / 2;
                //position other elements for mac
            }
            else {
                titleDisplay.left = 60;
                //position other elements for win
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Another - perhaps even better - approach would be to create two separate Skin's (one for Mac, one for Windows) and apply the correct Skin to your Windows. This would rid us of the continous if/else checking for capabilities.